Incorrect indexing of objects in the area (2d lists) python
I have implemented a program which should count on coordinates of an object in the area. The area is formed as a 2d list. The problem is that generally the output is correct, however, one object performs wrong coordinates. Firstly, there was a problem with indexing in the first function but then I moved it into the second function (cols.index(value)), (cols are columns). Maybe the this is the reasong or maybe I have incorrectly implemented something else? The program us not supposed to use numpy tool
Thanks for help in advance!
OBJECTS = {
    "h": "house",
    "s": "shop",
    "g": "gas station",
    "p": "pharmacy",
    "c": "cinema"
}


def check_area(char, row_n, col_n):
    """
    Explore a tile - if there is an animal, prints the
    location and name of the animal
    """
    if char in list(OBJECTS):
        print(f"Tile ({col_n}, {row_n}) disposes a {OBJECTS[char]}")


def check_region(td_list):
    """
    This function explores an entire field by calling the explore_tile
    function for each tile in the field.
    """
    for rows, cols in enumerate(td_list):
        for value in cols:
            if value != " ":
                check_area(value, rows, cols.index(value))


region = [
    [" ", "h", " ", " ", "p"],
    [" ", "s", "g", "s", " "],
    ["c", " ", "h", "s", " "]
]
check_region(region)

OUTPUT:
Tile (1, 0) disposes a house
Tile (4, 0) disposes a pharmacy
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (2, 1) disposes a gas station
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (0, 2) disposes a cinema
Tile (2, 2) disposes a house
Tile (3, 2) disposes a shop

Your problem is with this line:
check_area(value, rows, cols.index(value))

when you have two of the same value in a row (e.g. s in row 1), cols.index returns the index of the first matching value. So you get
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (2, 1) disposes a gas station
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop

instead of
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (2, 1) disposes a gas station
Tile (3, 1) disposes a shop

This is easily fixed by just enumerating the column values instead of using cols.index:
def check_region(td_list):
    """
    This function explores an entire field by calling the explore_tile
    function for each tile in the field.
    """
    for row, cols in enumerate(td_list):
        for col, value in enumerate(cols):
            if value != " ":
                check_area(value, row, col)

Output:
Tile (1, 0) disposes a house
Tile (4, 0) disposes a pharmacy
Tile (1, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (2, 1) disposes a gas station
Tile (3, 1) disposes a shop
Tile (0, 2) disposes a cinema
Tile (2, 2) disposes a house
Tile (3, 2) disposes a shop


Ah, yeah, obviously. Was so close, I was experimenting with the second "enumerate" but somewhy was putting "enumerate(rows)" to reach the correct order of columns. Thank for help!
